# how to check for memory leaks in android app developed in kony platform

Tags: memory, profiler, android-memory, temenos-quantum

I have got a hybrid android  app which was developed using Kony platform.
I need to identify memory usage of the app.
Please say me what tools to be used to identify the memory usage and memory leaks ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android tools mentioned in the below link, 
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Also, Kony also provides profiling option, but in turn it also relies on the native tools provided by Android.

Hope this answers.